# How to switch to nested framesets using Python Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, frames, frameset

I need to reach a target frame with Xpath = `html/frameset/frameset[1]/frame[2]`.

The HTML tree of the web site is as follows (the target frame is marked with a red *):
[image]

The web page is a chat room and I want to get the input box and the send button.

The following code logs into the chat room and tries to get to the target frame, but it fails there (Selenium hangs while trying to switch to that frame):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/yky/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver.get('http://ip131.ek21.com/oaca_1/?ot=1')

### Log into chat room:
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mlogin"]/form/ul/li[1]/input'))).send_keys("UserOne")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mlogin"]/form/div/span').click()
time.sleep(6)

### NONE of these works:
#driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("frame[name='ta']"))
#driver.switch_to.frame("ta")
#driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('html/frameset/frameset[1]/frame[2]'))
#driver.switch_to.frame(2);

inputbox = driver.find_element_by_name("says_temp")
sendbutton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='送出']"));
```

I find the suggestion to ignore `framesets` to be very beguiling, as it doesn't make sense when the `framesets` contain other frames as a tree structure.  Also, the problem is that the first `frameset` does not contain any `frame`; it just contains another `frameset`.  So there is no way for Selenium to switch to the first `frameset`.

Please help!!

Comment: @ArundeepChohan  But there are no `frames` in the top `frameset`!

Comment: @ArundeepChohan:  No good, it freezes as the other methods.  I found that by using Firefox driver it works simply with  `driver.switch_to.frame("ta")`.  But not the Chrome driver.

Comment: Selenium ignores `framesets` and requires you to switch into a `frame` within a `frameset` in order to access the deeper layers.  But if the `frameset` contains no `frames` then there is no way to access the deeper layers.  Guess this behavior is flawed.    The Firefox driver doesn't act like that, so I'll just use Firefox now.